# Bitcoin Core - When is fAllowWitness evaluated to true?

Tags: bitcoin-core, segregated-witness

In Bitcoin Core, when is `fAllowWitness` evaluated to `true`?

[transaction.h](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/primitives/transaction.h#L198)

```
const bool fAllowWitness = !(s.GetVersion() & SERIALIZE_TRANSACTION_NO_WITNESS);
```

In particular, I cant figure out the value of `s.GetVersion()`

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing a grep on `SERIALIZE_TRANSACTION_NO_WITNESS` shows that it's ORed with `PROTOCOL_VERSION` when creating a `CDataStream` object for example. This is the first clue that the no witness flag is to be found along with the version protocol.

A little more digging shows that this define is used when building a Tx message in lines [1105-1126 of net_processing.cpp (v0.15.0.1)](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/fb7b5293844ea6adc5dcf5ad0a0c5890b4495939/src/net_processing.cpp#L1105-L1126):

```
        else if (inv.type == MSG_TX || inv.type == MSG_WITNESS_TX)
        {
            // Send stream from relay memory
            bool push = false;
            auto mi = mapRelay.find(inv.hash);
            int nSendFlags = (inv.type == MSG_TX ? SERIALIZE_TRANSACTION_NO_WITNESS : 0);
            if (mi != mapRelay.end()) {
                connman.PushMessage(pfrom, msgMaker.Make(nSendFlags, NetMsgType::TX, *mi->second));
                push = true;
            } else if (pfrom->timeLastMempoolReq) {
                auto txinfo = mempool.info(inv.hash);
                // To protect privacy, do not answer getdata using the mempool when
                // that TX couldn't have been INVed in reply to a MEMPOOL request.
                if (txinfo.tx && txinfo.nTime <= pfrom->timeLastMempoolReq) {
                    connman.PushMessage(pfrom, msgMaker.Make(nSendFlags, NetMsgType::TX, *txinfo.tx));
                    push = true;
                }
            }
            if (!push) {
                vNotFound.push_back(inv);
            }
        }
```

The above code shows that the `int` variable `nSendFlags` may contain the no witness flag. Later, `msgMaker.Make` will use this variable to create the Tx message as shown in line  [1119](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/fb7b5293844ea6adc5dcf5ad0a0c5890b4495939/src/net_processing.cpp#L1119):

```
                    connman.PushMessage(pfrom, msgMaker.Make(nSendFlags, NetMsgType::TX, *txinfo.tx));
```

You can then follow the serialization by looking at the class `CNetMsgMaker` in `netmessagemaker.h` which itself uses `CVectorWriter` to serialize the data.

To summarize, the `GetVersion()` value is built using the protocol version optionally ORed with the `SERIALIZE_TRANSACTION_NO_WITNESS`. This value is never sent over the wire. It's used only to control the serialization of the Tx message.